# Automate description in WhatsApp

Tags: android, whatsapp, termux

How can I automate description in WhatsApp

I want to do like discord: if I'm online, it show "Online", if I have no battery it shows "No battery", and all that.

So I want to modify whatsapp description from my **Android Phone**, and **NO** other devices

I thinked about termux and TermuxAPI, but I didn't found packages to change WhatsApp Description

And I don't have a WhatsApp API Key, just a phone number.

What packages in termux, or other app can make this project?